# Tuple in view error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tuples, view

I have a partial view with:

```
@model Tuple<string, bool, List<Tuple<string, string, bool>>>

@if (Model != null)
{
    <text>
        <div id="multiple-selection-ddl">
            <select multiple="multiple" id="@(Model.Item1)_ddl">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Item3)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Item1" @(item.Item3 ? "selected" : "")>@item.Item2</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>

    </text>
}
```

which is called from Controller as :

```
return PartialView("_MSelectDropDown", new Tuple<string, bool, List<Tuple<string, string, bool>>>(controlId, isDisabled, GroupList));
```

But my view is not rendered got an error '>' is missing.
Can anyone tell me where I am wrong. Am I wrong on using the tuple?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the ">" inbetween the following, is the thing causing no rendering:

```
@(item.Item3 ? "selected" : "")>@item.Item2
```

Razor can't decide if it's a part of the executable code or the DOM.